# Error in .txt Play! template, works as .xml

Tags: playframework

I'm running into a really strange error in one simple txt template. There is no error when I serve it as XML, so the error has nothing to do with the template itself, nor the involved routes. Is this a bug in Play! (I'm using 1.2.4)?

This is the error message when requesting /robots.txt:

```
No route found 
No route able to invoke action PublicController.sitemap with arguments {} was found.

----------
In /app/views/PublicController/robots.txt (around line 1)

> 1: Sitemap: @@{PublicController.sitemap()}

This exception has been logged with id 69kj6fdbk
```

This is the template of robots.txt:

```
Sitemap: @@{PublicController.sitemap()}
```

This is the associated route:

```
GET    /robots.txt    PublicController.robots(format:'txt')
GET    /sitemap.xml   PublicController.sitemap(format:'xml')
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, this seems to be a bug in Play! I found the following in `ActionDefinition Router.reverse(String, Map<String, Object>)` from line 461:

```
if (!(Http.Request.current() == null ? "" : Http.Request.current().format).equals(route.staticArgs.get("format"))) {
    allRequiredArgsAreHere = false;
    break;
}
continue;
```

where the `break` leads to a `NoRouteFoundException`. I don't see why the request format must be checked during reverse routing. Reverse routing is used to generate links, and not responses or anything similar. Maybe this may have side effects on redirects, because `Controller.redirect(String, boolean, Object...)` uses `reverse` and may rely on this behaviour (does a HTTP redirect even allow content-type or format?). Anyway, the main Play! tests pass in my play fork.

I filed a bug report [here](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1467).

Answer (score 0):

Checking the error message, it says:

```
No route able to invoke action PublicController.sitemap with arguments {}
```

That means that in your routes file you lack something like

```
GET  /sitemap   PublicController.sitemap()
```

You may have an entry with `PublicController.sitemap()` that receives some parameters instead, which would explain the issue.

**Edit on update:**

In case you didn't check teh comments, as Maenu mentions in them, the issue is having different formats. Robots has a content type of "text/plain" and sitemap of "text/xml", which are incompatible.

The way would be to remove the format from the routes and try to set it in the controller using:

```
renderText(...)
renderXml(...)
```

See [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers).

Comment: PublicController.sitemap() doesn't take any parameters. The strange thing is, that if I change everything that was "txt" to "xml", including the file extension of the template, it works (although it the template is not valid XML then).

Comment: But you have 'PublicController.sitemap()' declared in your routes file?

Comment: Yes I do (I updated the question). But now observed that it may have to do with the explicitly setting of the format in the routes. Because when I change every "txt" to "html" it doesn't work either. So I guess it only worked with "xml", because both robots and sitemap formats are XML. Thus I believe now that this is an issue with the Router, because I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work. I also ruled out that "secure()" could have an issue, because it behaves the same without it.